# Chat like over line output of puts

Tags: ruby, rubygems, format, chat, display

im looking for a way to write code above the command line.
Like in chats, where the thing you've typed is displayed above the input line.

For example:

```
def output(arg1, arg2)
puts arg1 + ":" + arg2
end


puts "-" *30
print "What do you want to say? > "
written_line = gets.chomp
output(username, written_line)
```

what I want to display, if I type "My Name is Tim" is:

```
Tim: My Name is Tim
---------------------------------
What do you want to say? > _
```

Is there an Idea outside how to do it like this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like this?

```
def clear_line
    print "\e[2K" # Clear entire line
end

def move_up(n)
    print "\e[#{n}F" # Move to the beginning of n lines up
end

def positioning_to_output
    move_up(2)
    clear_line
end

def output(arg1, arg2)
    positioning_to_output
    puts arg1 + " :" + arg2
    clear_line
    puts "-" *30
end

username = "Jim Kirk"

4.times do
    print "What do you want to say? > "
    written_line = gets.chomp
    output(username, written_line)
end
```

Tested on macOS, thanks to escapes sequeces found [here](https://shiroyasha.svbtle.com/escape-sequences-a-quick-guide-1)

Comment: Damn you... that is AWESOME! Thank you very much for that solution!